# Getting parent of work item through REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

We are developing an Azure DevOps extension to push changes to work items to an external system.

We would like to maintain/preserve the hierarchy in Azure DevOps (Epic-> Feature -> PBI/Bug) in the target system, so we need to figure out which parent a work item has.

When pulling the Work item entity from the API, it looks like this (abbreviated a bit)

```js
{
    "id": 5202,
    "rev": 2,
    "fields": {
        "System.WorkItemType": "Task",
        "System.State": "To Do",
        "System.Reason": "New task",
        "System.CreatedDate": "2017-10-30T10:18:06.233Z",
        "System.CreatedBy": "Jesper Lund Stocholm",
        "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority": 2,
        "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork": 23.0,
        "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate": "2017-10-30T10:18:06.233Z",
    },
    "_links": {
            "self": {
            "href": "https://{myorg}.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workItems/5202"
        },
        "workItemUpdates": {
            "href": "https://{myorg}.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workItems/5202/updates"
        },
        "workItemRevisions": {
            "href": "https://{myorg}.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workItems/5202/revisions"
        },
        "workItemHistory": {
            "href": "https://{myorg}.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workItems/5202/history"
        },
        "html": {
            "href": "https://{myorg}.visualstudio.com/web/wi.aspx?pcguid=e5d991b2-9879-497c-85fb-c618f144a9c5&id=5202"
        },
        "workItemType": {
            "href": "https://{myorg}.visualstudio.com/6847ebed-cbca-4510-8baa-228c7c55ba8d/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Task"
        },
        "fields": {
            "href": "https://{myorg}.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/fields"
        }
    },
    "url": "https://{myorg}.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workItems/5202"
}
```

The obvious place to look is here https://{myorg}.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/fields

But we cannot find any traces of references to "parent entity".

Can it be true that this value is not exposed?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can get all the work items links (Parent, Childs etc.) by adding the `$expand=relations` to the api string.

**For example:**

```
https://shaykia.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workItems/4?$expand=relations
```

In the result you will see "relations" section:

```js
"relations": [
    {
      "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward",
      "url": "http:/shaykia.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workItems/11",
      "attributes": {
        "isLocked": false
      }
    },
    {
      "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse",
      "url": "http://shaykia.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workItems/3",
      "attributes": {
        "isLocked": false
      }
    }
  ],
```

`System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse` is for for parent (in this case, the work item with id 3 he is the parent), and `System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward` is for child.

Comment: Thank you, @shayki!

Comment: @shayki How would I filter only those relations to get only those with specific attributes?

Comment: @Andreas I don't think you can filter in the URL, you need to filter the result.

Comment: Is `?$expand=relations` anywhere in the docs? I can't find it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP#workitemrelation